# Are you allowed to use a method inside the init method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I just started learning about OOP in python3 and we made this little class today.

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side

    def show_perimeter(self):
        print(self.side * 4)

test_square = Square(10)
test_square.show_perimeter()
>> 40
```

Now I'm thinking if it's possible to get the value of the perimeter while creating the object, something like...

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
        self.permiter = get_perimeter(self)

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.side * 4

test_square = Square(10)
print(test_square.perimeter)
```

Is this something you're able to do?
If so, is it a good practice?

**If not, what would be the best way to get the perimeter by just using the side?**

Comment: It is a good practice. You should implement an algorithm such as the perimeter calculation in one place so that it only needs validation once and you don't have to search around your code if it ever needs to be changed. Also, its something you can leverage later when creating subclasses (consider an equilateral triangle that could share `__init__` with a change to `get_perimeter`) ... but you likely haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing special about the `__init__` method other than it is invoked automatically as part of the construction of an object (`__new__` creates the object, and `__init__` initializes it).  Therefore, you can do whatever you need to do within it.  However, you need to make sure that you don't inadvertently do things that would cause operations on a partially initialized object.  The use of `@property` below can solve most of these edge cases.

The only difference here is it is better form to call `self.method()` rather than `method(self)` in most cases.

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
        self.permiter = self.get_perimeter()

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.side * 4

test_square = Square(10)
print(test_square.perimeter)
```

However, I'd like to point out that a property might be better in this case:

```
class Square():
  def __init__(self, side):
    self.side = side;

  @property
  def perimeter(self):
    return self.side * 4

x = Square(10)
print(x.perimeter)
>>> 40
```

In this case, the `@property` decorator converts the `perimeter` method to a property which can be accessed just like it is another attribute, but it is calculated at the time it is asked for.

Comment: It's not invoked as part of `__new__`; [`type.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L876) is responsible for both calling `__new__` and then (usually) calling `__init__` on the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm actually taking this idea for a homework of genetic algorithms so I needed to construct it from the start.

Comment: Edited as per @user2357112 comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's allowed, but it's also a lot more dangerous than people usually realize.

Say you have the following class:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cached_size = self.compute_size()
    def compute_size(self):
        return 1000
```

That seems to work fine on its own, but then if you try to subclass it:

```
class SubThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self, more_stuff):
        super().__init__()
        self.more_stuff = more_stuff
    def compute_size(self):
        return super().compute_size() + self.more_stuff

SubThing(5)
```

[Everything goes to pieces](https://ideone.com/gl3gIr), because `Thing.__init__` calls `SubThing.compute_size`, and `SubThing.compute_size` assumes `self.more_stuff` is ready, but it's not ready:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 9, in __init__
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in __init__
  File "./prog.py", line 12, in compute_size
AttributeError: 'SubThing' object has no attribute 'more_stuff'
```

---

You should essentially never call methods in `__init__` that you expect to be overridden, since your object is in a very precarious, half-constructed state, especially the parts of its state that subclasses are responsible for.

If you want to use your own class's version of a method and ignore overrides (dodging the problem of subclass state), you can call it directly:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cached_size = Thing.compute_size(self)
    def compute_size(self):
        return 1000
```

Some people might recommend having subclasses initialize their state before calling `super().__init__`, but that leads into a really nastily coupled mess of different classes depending on specific parts of other classes being ready. It's not going to decrease the number of problems you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll come back for this post later on we see subclasses

Comment: Probably best to just avoid inheritance entirely ;).  But on a more serious note, I appreciate this perspective. I always feel torn when I use a method for initialization of an attribute. This justifies my hesitation.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the method in the same class with `self`.

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
        self.perimeter = self.get_perimeter()

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.side * 4
```